# Google Script onFormSubmit()

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to autorun a script in the responses file for a Google Form whenever there is a submission to a Google Form.  It works if I run it manually but it cannot be run upon new submission.  Anyone advice?

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var form = FormApp.openById('1xuCZFmUEhbkZtUUU0bRS7HOHCerRfd2ebqc3OWPWr5Q');

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').forSpreadsheet(ss).onFormSubmit()
    .forForm(form)
    .create();
}
```

Comment: Triggers need to be created only once. You can manage your triggers at https://script.google.com/home/triggers

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create new trigger every time you open the spreadsheet. Maybe try to manually configure the installable trigger instead.

You will find step-by-step instructions [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

But be aware of the [limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions)